# Value of the first order of every customer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working on a school assignment where I have to look at the value of every first voucher value of a customer. Now I am working on it and I did manage to get the first date of each customer. However, when I put the value in the table it always takes the total sometimes of this customer ID so that some lines score considerably higher

**Code**

```
First transaction date = 
MINX(FILTER('Tekst','Tekst'[PCHN]='Tekst'[PCHN]),'Tekst'[Datum].[Date])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8YJ6.png)

Comment: School assignments have a very low rate of reply here on stack overflow. You might want to expand on your question more, give some input and expected output so people can test themselves. That being said, I don't know what your exact assignment is but this can be achieved with a table (in the visualisation pane). Then you will select 'Customer' and 'Date' and 'Value'. Put date on 'first' (in the 'values' tab under visualisations) and you will get a table that has the first voucher value a customer ever had.  Not everything in Power BI is achieved through DAX. :)

Comment: Thank you Max, next post I will be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Try making your first transaction date into a column:

```
First_transaction_date = CALCULATE(
    MIN('Table'[date]),
    FILTER(
        'Table',
        'Table'[customer]=EARLIER('Table'[customer])
        )
    )
```

Then calculate the corresponding value. I used SUM, so if multiple values are on the same date, it will sum them. If you want the min/max/mean of these values when multiple occur, that's up to you:

```
first_voucher_value = CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[value]),
    'Table'[First_transaction_date] == 'Table'[date])
```

I believe in your example:

- Table => Tekst,
- date = Date,
- customer = PCHN,
- value should be your 'voucher value column'.